# Annualized actual probability

Tags: default, default-risk

I have a dataset of bank loans over different periods. 
Let's say that most of the loans have a horizon over 5,10,15 years.
I obtain the actual default rate over these different type of loans.
I would like to annualize these default rates to make them comparable.
If I assume that the default rate is constant over time, is it appropriate to do:
$dr_a = 1 - (1-dr_y)^{(1/y)}$ where $dr_a$ is the annualized default rate and $dr_y$ is the observed default probability for the considered different class of loans?

Do you have any reference to suggest me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your formula seems correct under the simplifying assumptions as you can easily verify:

Assume annual default rate is d, and the portfolio size is N. In the first year, we will have N*d defaults. In second year, the number of obligors would have declined by the number of default in the previous year to N-N*d=N(1-d), so the number of defaults in the second year would be N(1-d)d, and so on. So the total number of defaults over n years is:

$D_n=Nd+N(1-d)d+,\dots,+N(1-d)^{n-1}d$

$D_n= Nd \frac{1-(1-d)^n}{1-(1-d)}$

$\frac{D_n}{N}=1-(1-d)^n $

The left hand side is the n-year default rate, and solving this for d, one year default rate, gives your formula.

There are a few technicalities as to how to account for attrition etc, for which the below is a good reference:

https://www.moodys.com/sites/products/DefaultResearch/2006200000425249.pdf

Comment: Thank you! this is the answer I needed it.